# Select column by value in another table column

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

**Table A**:

```
id | name
```

**Table B**:

```
id | hash | owners_id
```

`owners_id` contains the ids from table A.

Example:

**Table A**:

```
id | name
1  | James
2  | Jonas
```

**Table B**:

```
id | hash | owners_id
1  | j28sj | 1,2
```

Expect Result:

```
James | j28sj
Jonas | j28sj
```

Because both contain the ownerds_id

I'm trying to make a query that selects all the names from table A associates with table B `owners_id` column.

Comment: What type is owners_id? Is it an array, or a comma-separated string?

Comment: comma-separated string

Comment: Try now; I edited my answer for a comma-separated string and provided a working fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
    A.name,
    B.hash

FROM
     A
left JOIN B ON
    B.owners_id LIKE CONCAT('%', A.id, '%')
```

Note: The database you designed is poorly designed and it may not work it you have owners_id like 1,11,111 .so either you need to make seperate table with many to many relation or put leading zeros like 001,011,111

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways to do this. If you want to keep owners_id as a comma-separated string, it's a bit messy. You need to first parse the string into a list of integers to form the join condition:

```
SELECT A.name, B.hash FROM A 
LEFT JOIN B
ON find_in_set(A.id,B.owners_id) <> 0;
```

You may want to consider letting owners_id be an integer foreign key to Table A, if you can change your schema.

Here's a working SQL fiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/320477/4

Comment: @TiagoCastro Try now; I misunderstood schema in my first answer.